# Text Width in VB 6

Tags: vb6, scale, text-width

To check the Text Width, how to set the scale mode?

Is it -

> ```
>     Debug.Print .ScaleMode = 1
> ```

Or

> ```
>     Me.ScaleMode = 1
> ```

Which one does it work?

I test it with below code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim xStr As String
    xStr = "W"
    With frmLabel
        .Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Font.Size = 10
        'Debug.Print .ScaleMode = 1

        '0 to 7
        Me.ScaleMode = 7
        Debug.Print .TextWidth(xStr) ' TextWidth = 435
        .Font.Size = 14
        Debug.Print .TextWidth(xStr) ' TextWidth = 645
    End With
End Sub
```

How could I define the kind of measure or unit? I'm looking for inch.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this http://www.virtualsplat.com/tips/visual-basic-graphics.asp?

Answer (score 3):

In the context of a Form, UserControl, or UserDocument "Me" is already part of the namespace, so just use something like:

```
ScaleMode = vbInches
```

You can use redundant overqualification if you wish, as in:

```
Me.ScaleMode = vbInches
```

Since you can't write code inside of a PictureBox (and thus there is no local "Me" anyway) you are writing in the context of its container, so to set the property of a `picScrollbox` you'd write:

```
picScrollbox.ScaleMode = vbInches
```

The same is true for a Printer object.

But please avoid magic numbers and make use the intrinsic Enum `ScaleModeConstants` that provides symbolic names easier for the next guy to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
Me.Font.Name = "Arial"
Me.Font.Size = 10
Me.ScaleMode = vbInch ' 5
```

TextWidth returns the width if the text were output using Print with the current Font *of the Form*. You aren't setting the Font of the Form in the code in your question. Set **Me.Font**. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267168(v=vs.60).aspx

The value is returned in units as determined by ScaleMode property of the form. The possible values of ScaleMode are in the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445668(v=vs.60).aspx

Another time why not try context-sensitive help? In the VB6 IDE code view put the cursor in ScaleMode and press F1 to go straight to the ScaleMode topic in the docs.